# Why does my flutter app crash on Android 12?

Tags: android, flutter, crash, android-12

We are experiencing issues with our Flutter based app on Android 12 specifically. No other system seems affected.

The issues that occur cause a hard crash of the app and nothing reaches our exception monitoring tool.

One example stack trace:

```
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-95 rsrp=-94 rsrq=-7 rssnr=19 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=4 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=4
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-99 rsrp=-98 rsrq=-7 rssnr=17 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=4 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=4
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-99 rsrp=-98 rsrq=-7 rssnr=17 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
notifyListener: enabled=true, connected=true, dataConnected=false, networkType=LTE (4G), emergencyOnly=false, roaming=false, isDefault=false, fiveGAvailable=false, mmWave=false, showDisabledDataIcon=false, voWifiConnected=false, dataActivity=, simState=LOADED, cardOperator=OTHERS, simCardActivated=1
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-93 rsrp=-93 rsrq=-7 rssnr=16 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-91 rsrp=-91 rsrq=-10 rssnr=19 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
03-25 21:02:13.784 F/libc    (22599): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7308479630 in tid 23041 (1.raster), pid 22599 (aidhere.zanadio)
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/beyond1lteeea/beyond1:12/SP1A.210812.016/G973FXXUEGVB4:user/release-keys'
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): Revision: '26'
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): ABI: 'arm64'
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): Timestamp: 2022-03-25 21:02:13.865217058+0100
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): Process uptime: 67s
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): Cmdline: lang.product.organisation
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): pid: 22599, tid: 23041, name: 1.raster  >>> lang.product.organisation <<<
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): uid: 10349
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7308479630
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x0  000000730847a110  x1  000000730847a110  x2  000000730847ac00  x3  0000000000000000
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000007308479620  x6  000000730847a110  x7  0000000000000008
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x8  00000073084efa50  x9  00000073084efa50  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000007308479620
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x12 00000000000000af  x13 000000730847ac00  x14 00000000447a0000  x15 0000000039800000
03-25 21:02:14.163 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x16 00000000000000af  x17 00000000000000ac  x18 000000731a49c000  x19 000000758536f930
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x20 00000000000000a5  x21 00000000000000a2  x22 0000007585360afc  x23 00000000000000a5
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x24 00000000000000ac  x25 00000000000000af  x26 000000000000000d  x27 0000000000000007
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):     x28 0000000000000000  x29 000000000000014d
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):     lr  000000731c96e220  sp  0000007385789c70  pc  000000731c96e3fc  pst 0000000020000000
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318): backtrace:
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #00 pc 00000000003543fc  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #01 pc 00000000003541b8  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #02 pc 00000000004d7e10  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #03 pc 00000000004724f4  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #04 pc 000000000046b014  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #05 pc 000000000046b420  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #06 pc 000000000034b744  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #07 pc 0000000000602af4  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #08 pc 00000000002faa7c  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #09 pc 00000000002faabc  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #10 pc 0000000000329d34  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #11 pc 000000000032a5e8  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #12 pc 000000000032a07c  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #13 pc 0000000000331b28  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #14 pc 00000000002fd09c  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #15 pc 00000000002fff20  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #16 pc 0000000000016bb0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+912) (BuildId: 176a88c64d70f517a4c1c58b40932d90)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #17 pc 00000000000167b8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: 176a88c64d70f517a4c1c58b40932d90)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #18 pc 0000000000017284  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100) (BuildId: 246f3516484d421035372a67caa5a740)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #19 pc 0000000000300030  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #20 pc 00000000002fc950  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #21 pc 00000000002fe830  /data/app/~~2eiiCJ7Ak-ZC7Z6U7SE2lA==/lang.product.organisation-dtglboqK8ZK11lr4ek7Rgg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 72e477eb571a57ba1286df3d00a067adb310a1cd)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #22 pc 00000000000b4ad8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264) (BuildId: 721f9a1e738668c9f29a0ef6a2870cb9)
03-25 21:02:14.164 F/DEBUG   (23318):       #23 pc 0000000000052c08  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 721f9a1e738668c9f29a0ef6a2870cb9)
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-95 rsrp=-94 rsrq=-11 rssnr=14 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-91 rsrp=-90 rsrq=-10 rssnr=16 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-95 rsrp=-94 rsrq=-10 rssnr=16 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-99 rsrp=-98 rsrq=-10 rssnr=17 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-95 rsrp=-94 rsrq=-10 rssnr=15 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=Invalid,mGsm=Invalid,mWcdma=Invalid,mTdscdma=Invalid,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-91 rsrp=-91 rsrq=-11 rssnr=16 cqiTableIndex=2147483647 cqi=12 ta=2147483647 level=4 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=Invalid,SignalBarInfo{ lteLevel=3 },rat=14,primary=CellSignalStrengthLte} level=3
```

We've tried updating dependencies (incl. Flutter version up until 2.10.3).

One key problem we are facing is that the issue is not consistently reproducible and no developer had the problem so far. Only actual app users seem affected and the problem also does not appear to occur the same way for the affected users. For example: After deleting data / cache for the app users are able to work with the app as expected for a day or so and then misbehaviour starts again.

Can you think of anything specific that might be causing such a problem?

Comment: You're looking at a native crash in the flutter .so.  SEGV_ACCESSERR generally means someone tried to execute code held in non-executable memory.  Assuming you don't have an attacker, its likely a bug in the .so file-  a bug in the flutter framework.